# spreee-commerce adding second language

Tags: internationalization, e-commerce, locale, spree

i need to add support for Spanish in my spree project.
tried various approaches, the URL way is out for me (not wanted), the globalizer3 doesnt really do what i want. some other extensions dont work, some kill the site, etc.

so i have added

```
gem 'spree_i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git'
gem 'globalize3'
```

to my gemfile, while the globalizer willl most likely be scratched (doesnt do what i want).

i have added a "def_lang" column to "spree_users" to store the locale in, which is set by a dropdown box on user signup. available are "en" and "es".

the piece of code and repeated advice i found over the last 14 hours is this:

add the following code to the application_controller.rb (or base_controller.rb according to someone else)

```
before_filter :set_locale

protected
 def set_locale
 I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

which i my case should be

```
before_filter :set_locale

 protected #<-this is not in all tips
  def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:def_lang] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

to make it short, it does NOT work.
the language support for spanish works as can be proven by setting in "application.rb"

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

and the site is translated.

why doesnt it work?
how to make it work?
is there anything else i can use to get a second language to work on a per-user basis?

please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

`params[:def_lang]` will only be available for the sign up request, not for subsequent requests. You probably want to get this to use `current_user && current_user.locale` rather than checking for `params[:def_lang]`